# How to access its own iframe from contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe list like that:

```
<iframe src="foo">
    <button class="dissmiss">Close</button>
    <script>
        // Do job here...
    </script>
</iframe>
<iframe src="bar">
    <button class="dissmiss">Close</button>
    <script>
        // Do job here...
    </script>
</iframe>
.
.
.
<iframe src="baz">
    <button class="dissmiss">Close</button>
    <script>
        // Do job here...
    </script>
</iframe>
```

How can I get the iframe with js or jquery?
I want to remove the iframe when the button is clicked:

```
parentIframe.remove();
```

PS: They have same domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: do you want to get the contents of any iframe. Please confirm

Comment: ...or a particular one at a given time

Comment: @kundanKarn No I only want to dissmiss the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any *iframe window* (if not cross-domain) you can refer to the `iframe HTMLElement` on the parent page with

[`window.frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frameElement)

When using this, you don't need to know `id` or `class` of the `iframe`, or count `iframe` tags within a parent document.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to access the content of an Iframe:** Try to assign some unique id to the `iframe`.

Try this, hope it will work

```
 parent.$('body').find('Iframe').html();
```